# Circle Loader going to 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get this circle loader working properly but having difficulty. I can do some basic animations, but this code which I found on CodePen is a bit above my pay-grade. I'm trying to use it to understand what's happening.

My objective is that the loader doesn't go all the way around the circumference of the circle. Say, only 68% of the way and stops. Or 98%. But I'm thus far unable to locate the property/value which determines how far the loader goes around the circle.

I've tried manipulating the keyframes on the right loader class to no avail as well as the transform-origin property. No dice.

Code:

```css
#circle-loader-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 200px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#circle-loader-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#circle-loader-wrap div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#circle-loader-wrap .loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#circle-loader-wrap .left-wrap {
  left: 0;
}

#circle-loader-wrap .left-wrap .loader {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
  animation: loading-left 20s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: loading-left 20s infinite linear;
}

#circle-loader-wrap .right-wrap {
  left: 50%;
}

#circle-loader-wrap .right-wrap .loader {
  left: -100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
  animation: loading-right 20s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: loading-right 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes loading-left {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-right {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div id="circle-loader-wrap">
        <div class="left-wrap">
          <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-wrap">
          <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the values in the keyframes, and review how keyframes work. What do the percentages refer to, and what happens at 100%? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the docs for an hour. The keyframes percentages refer to how the image will appear at that point in time in the duration of the full animation. The full animation effect is defined by the animation property in the referenced class. In this case "animation: loading-right 20s infinite linear". But I've played with the keyframes and can't get it to stop the animation at a particular point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pasting a snippet below which does what you want.

I have written my explanation of what's going on directly into the code comments next to the css rules that are doing the corresponding animation.

In case anything is still unclear, post a comment.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    #circle-loader-wrap {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -10px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 200px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
        width: 170px;
        height: 170px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: green;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap div {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap .loader {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1000px;
        background-color: pink;
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap .left-wrap {
        left: 0;
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap .left-wrap .loader {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
        animation: loading-left 5s infinite linear;
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap .right-wrap {
        left: 50%;
    }

    #circle-loader-wrap .right-wrap .loader {
        left: -100%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
        animation: loading-right 5s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes loading-left {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        25%, 100% {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes loading-right {
        0%, 25% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        50%, 100% {
/*          the following is for the second half of the cicrle */
/*          180deg means one half of the cicle or 50% of the cicle */
/*          So, 1% is gonna be 180/50 = 3.6deg */
/*          If you want 68%, then you have 18% left for the second half of the circle */
/*          To get 18%: 18x3.6 = 64.8deg */
            transform: rotate(64.8deg);
/*          Note: The transformation will happen between 25% and 50% of the total time which is 5 seconds in this case; So, it's gonna take 1.25 seconds. */
/*          In other words, it will take the same amount of time as for the first half of the circle which will make the transformation in the second half appear to be slower because it has the same time to cover a much shorter distance */
/*          Between 50% and 100% nothing happens. */
/*          That's your "pause" in this animation although technically it's not a pause. */
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="container mt-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <p>68% in this case:</p>
            <div id="circle-loader-wrap">
                <div class="left-wrap">
                    <div class="loader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-wrap">
                    <div class="loader"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>The comments next to the corresponding css rules show how to adjust.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also note: I ripped out the vendor prefixes because you don't really need those nowadays for those css rules.

Comment: P.S. Just in case you wanted to use this as some kind of a progress animation, you'll now realize that this particular animation is not terribly suitable for that. But you can always post another question if you are looking for something in that direction.

Comment: For an easier way to control the timing of your animation, you could set the total duration to 100s. Then 1% would equal 1 second. Or you could set the total duration to 10s. Then 1% would equal 0.1 second etc.